# creating procedure in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, timestamp, cursor, procedure, dateadd

I am trying to create procedure in mysql workbench. but i am not able to fix errors in procedure.
below are my tables and data

create table product(pid int primary key,productname varchar(45))
insert into product values(10,'a')
insert into product values(12,'a')
insert into product values(13,'a')

create table productdata(prid int primary key,prname varchar(45))
insert into productdata values(1,'a')
insert into productdata values(2,'b')
insert into productdata values(3,'c')

create table pr_status(pesid int primary key,pid int references product(pid),stage varchar(20),statusdate varchar(45))

insert into pr_status values(1,10,'4','2018-05-23')
insert into pr_status values(4,10,'4','2018-05-23')
insert into pr_status values(2,12,'5','2018-05-24')
insert into pr_status values(3,13,'4','2018-05-25')

create table work(wid int primary key,prid int  references productdata(prid),pid int references product(pid))

insert into work values(1,2,10)
insert into work values(2,2,12)
insert into work values(3,1,13)

select * from product
select * from productdata 
select * from pr_status
select * from work

i am trying to get data from this tables using procedure.

```
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_mysql_while_loop$$
 DROP TEMPORARY  TABLE IF EXISTS esubmit$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_mysql_while_loop()
 BEGIN

    DECLARE  v_startdate VARCHAR(45), v_enddate VARCHAR(45)
SET  v_startdate='2018-05-22'
set v_enddate='2018-05-28'
declare v_sql longtext
create temporary table #esubmit(id int auto_increment,Name varchar(100));
SET v_sql = 'ALTER TABLE #esubmit ADD ';
declare v_status int
declare v_count int
set v_status=0
set v_count=1
while(v_status!=1)
do
/* print cast(TIMESTAMPADD(day, v_count, cast(v_startdate as datetime(3))) as date) */
/* print cast(v_enddate as date) */
if(cast(TIMESTAMPADD(day, v_count, cast(v_startdate as datetime(3))) as date)=cast(v_enddate as date))
then
/* print v_sql */
 set v_status=1;
 set v_sql+=Concat('[',cast(TIMESTAMPADD(day,v_count, cast(v_startdate as datetime(3))) as varchar(45)),'] varchar(45)') 
else
set v_sql+=Concat('[',cast(TIMESTAMPADD(day,v_count, cast(v_startdate as datetime(3))) as varchar(45)),'] varchar(45),') 
end if;
set v_count=v_count+1
end while
set @stmt_str = v_sql;
prepare stmt from @stmt_str;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
declare v_cid int
declare v_eid int
declare v_setdate varchar(45)
 c
fetch next from c into v_cid,v_eid
while(NOT_FOUND=0)
do
declare v_setcnt int
declare v_getdate varchar(45)
declare v_getname varchar(45)

open c1
fetch next from c1 into v_setdate
/* print v_setdate */
declare v_s int
set v_s=0
declare v_qry longtext
select prname into v_getname from productdata where prid=v_cid
/* print v_getname */
set v_qry=Concat('insert into #esubmit values(''',v_getname,''',')
/* print v_qry */
while(NOT_FOUND=0)
do

/* print CONVERT(CAST(v_setdate AS CHAR(24)), DATETIME) */
    select count(pid) into v_setcnt from pr_status where pid=(select pid from work where pid=v_eid and prid=v_cid) and
    cast(statusdate as date)=cast(v_setdate as date) and stage BETWEEN '4' AND '5'  group by pid,statusdate 
/* print v_setcnt */
    select statusdate into v_getdate from pr_status where pid=(select pid from work where pid=v_eid and prid=v_cid) and
    cast(statusdate as date) =cast(v_setdate as date) and stage BETWEEN '4' AND '5'  group by pid,statusdate 

    set v_qry=v_qry+cast(v_setcnt as varchar(10)),','
    /* print v_qry */
    fetch next from c1 into v_setdate
    set v_setcnt=0

end while
set v_qry=concat(substring(v_qry,0,char_length(rtrim(v_qry))),')')
set @stmt_str = v_qry;
prepare stmt from @stmt_str;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
set v_qry=''

deallocate c1   
fetch next from c into v_cid,v_eid
end while

END
```

but i am getting below error
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin if(cast(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, v_count, cast(v_startdate as datetime(3))) as da' at line 15   0.000 sec